# timeout waiting for the application to start in flutter (android studio)

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

After launching my Flutter application stopped building on a device.

[See The Run Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x33pv.png)

Comment: is this a Question ?

Comment: @RaoufRahiche this is a solution for a problem that i faced now without any answer on the internet so I loved sharing this solution with you

Comment: okay don't share the answer in question you can make it as separate answer

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

pubspec.yaml> Packages upgrade

(Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...) wait for couple of moments

Have Fun

Comment: Might be under Flutter tab when you right click on pubspec.yaml in android studio, otherwise surprisingly worked for me, while I was seeing `resolving dependencies` as well as the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX i solved this issue using

```
$ brew install gradle
```